# EF Core 6.0.13 generates TSQL queries non-existent column, resulting in SqlException: Invalid column name 'TrackId'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

*Edited*
I'll lay all the pertinent information out - but I did want to mention, in case it might be important, that this column **USED** to exist and it **USED** to be in my model. I added it because I thought this table was supposed to link to Tracks. After some clarification, I took it back out.

When I took it out, I did **NOT** receive this error.  I coded and tested for more than 2 months without this column and everything worked just fine.  It was only after I added/removed some other columns that it went rogue on me! Those other columns are not causing any errors and are working just fine in code.

Database is Azure SQL Database.

Track contains TrackCourses.  Track/TrackCourses is a lot like the model DB in Sql Server.  It only serves as a template to create.  When you create a ScheduledTrack, it USES the information from Track to create the ScheduledTrack instance and then creates a ScheduledClass instance for EACH of the TrackCourses defined in the track Courses table.  Track and Scheduled Track are not the same object. And after the Scheduling of the ScheduledTrack, there is no further database or code relationship between Tracks and ScheduledTracks. TrackCourses entity object has a link to the courses...but Courses object does NOT have a link back to TrackCourses in code. Could this be my problem?

[image]

Pertinent Model data
Scheduled Class

```cs
    public class ScheduledClass : AuditableEntity  // (gives ID & Created/Modified columns)
    {
        public ScheduledClass()
        {
            Scheduling = new SchedulingInformation();
            Cancellation = new CancellationInformation();
            CoursewareDetails = new CoursewareDetails();
            Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollment>();
            Sessions = new HashSet<ClassSession>();
        }

        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public int? ScheduledTrackId { get; set; }
        public SchedulingInformation Scheduling { get; set; }
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
        public int ClassroomId { get; set; }
        public StudentCapacity StudentCapacity { get; set; }
        public CancellationInformation Cancellation { get; set; }
        public bool ShowOnWeb { get; set; }
        public ClassStatusEnum ClassStatus { get; set; }
        public decimal Retail { get; set; }
        public decimal InternalCost { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public int ScheduledTypeId { get; set; }
        public DeliveryLength DeliveryLength { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public int? SeatModalityLookup { get; set; }
        public int? LocationLookup { get; set; }
        public int CoursewareDetailsId { get; set; }

        public virtual Classroom Classroom { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual CoursewareDetails CoursewareDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual ScheduledTrack ScheduledTrack { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClassSession> Sessions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

Scheduled Track

```cs
    public class ScheduledTrack : Entity<int>
    {
        public ScheduledTrack()
        {
            Classes = new HashSet<ScheduledClass>();
        }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Abbrev { get; set; }
        public int? TimePeriodLookup { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ScheduledClass> Classes { get; set; }       
    }
```

It USED to link to Track, shown in case someone wants to cling to its importance.

```
    public class Track : AuditableEntity
    {
        public Track()
        {
            Courses = new HashSet<TrackCourse>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Abbrev { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TrackCourse> Courses { get; set; }

    }
```

My Context Class (It is quite large with wholly unrelated junk that was taken out).

```cs
    public partial class CareContext : DbContext
    {
        public readonly IHttpContextAccessor _Http;

        public CareContext() { }
        public CareContext(IHttpContextAccessor ctx, DbContextOptions<CareContext> opt) : base(opt)
        {
            _Http = ctx;
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ScheduledClass> ScheduledClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ScheduledTrack> ScheduledTracks { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Track> Tracks { get; set; }

        #endregion
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ScheduledClassConfigurationProfile());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ScheduledTrackConfigurationProfile());

            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
               .Navigation(d => d.CoursewareDetails)
               .AutoInclude();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ScheduledClass>()
               .Navigation(d => d.CoursewareDetails)
               .AutoInclude();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ScheduledClass>()
               .Navigation(d => d.Classroom)
               .AutoInclude();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>()
                .Navigation(d => d.Student)
                .AutoInclude();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }       
    }
```

Appropriate ScheduledClass EF Fluent API code...

```
    internal class ScheduledClassConfigurationProfile : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ScheduledClass>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ScheduledClass> builder)
        {
            builder
                .ToTable("Classes");

            builder
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("ClassId");

            builder
                .Property(x => x.ClassStatus)
                .HasColumnName("ClassStatusId");

            builder
                .Property(e => e.Client).HasMaxLength(50);

            builder
                .Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            builder
                .Property(e => e.InternalCost)
                .HasColumnType("smallmoney");

            builder
                .Property(e => e.ModifiedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            builder
                .Property(e => e.TimeZone)
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            builder
                .Property(e => e.Version)
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            builder
                .OwnsOne(x => x.Scheduling);

            builder
                .OwnsOne(x => x.DeliveryLength);

            builder
                .OwnsOne(x => x.StudentCapacity);

            builder
                .OwnsOne(x => x.Cancellation);

            builder
                .HasOne(x => x.ScheduledTrack);

            builder
                .HasMany(x => x.Enrollments);

            builder
               .HasOne(x => x.CoursewareDetails)
               .WithOne(x => x.Class)
               .HasForeignKey<ScheduledClass>(x => x.CoursewareDetailsId);

            builder.HasOne(d => d.ScheduledTrack)
                .WithMany(p => p.Classes)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ScheduledTrackId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Classes_ScheduledTracks");

        }
    }
```

(Note: I've tried it with and without the `.HasConstraintName()` above).

Appropriate ScheduledTrack EF Fluent API code...

```
    internal class ScheduledTrackConfigurationProfile : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ScheduledTrack>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ScheduledTrack> builder)
        {
            builder
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasColumnName("ScheduledTrackId");

            builder.Property(e => e.Abbrev)
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            builder.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(200);

            builder.Property(e => e.StartDate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime");

            builder.HasMany(x => x.Classes)
                .WithOne(x => x.ScheduledTrack)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
        }
    }
```

EF Code used to get the data...

```
       public ScheduledClass FindBy(int id)
       {
           return _DB.ScheduledClasses
               .Include(d => d.Course)
               //.Include("ScheduledTrack")
               .Include(d => d.Enrollments)
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
       }
```

I commented out the above include just to make sure that it was no other relationship that was causing me harm.

I ended switched to separate code to load the Scheduled Track which I called elsewhere...

```
    var results = _DB.ScheduledTracks
     .Include("Classes")
     .Include("Classes.Course")
     .Include("Classes.Enrollments")
     .First(x => x.Id == id);
```

This gave the same error, so I thought, "We should even isolate this further - remove all child relationships to the ScheduledTrack" which yielded this...

```
    public ScheduledTrack LoadMinimal(int id)
    {
      var results = _DB.ScheduledTracks
          .First(x => x.Id == id);
      return results;
    }
```

No dice.

Finally, my error stack...

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'TrackId'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action<Action> wrapCloseInAction)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, bool callerHasConnectionLock, bool asyncClose)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, out bool dataReady)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, string resetOptionsString, bool isInternal, bool forDescribeParameterEncryption, bool shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, bool isAsync, int timeout, out Task task, bool asyncWrite, bool inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, bool describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, TaskCompletionSource<object> completion, int timeout, out Task task, out bool usedCache, bool asyncWrite, bool inRetry, string method)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, TResult> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, ExecutionResult<TResult>> verifySucceeded)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.MoveNext()
> System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, out bool found)
> lambda_method741(Closure , QueryContext )
> System.Linq.Queryable.First<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
> UnifiedCare.Repositories.ScheduledTracks.LoadMinimal(int id)
> UnifiedCare.Controllers.ViewComponents.ScheduledTrackNameViewComponent.Invoke(int scheduledTrackName) in ScheduledTrackName.cs

- ```
        var Track = _ScheduledTracks.LoadMinimal(scheduledTrackName);
  ```

lambda_method738(Closure , object , object[] )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeSyncCore(ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object component, ViewComponentContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.InvokeCoreAsync(ViewComponentDescriptor descriptor, object arguments)
AspNetCore._Views_ScheduledClass_CareerDetails.<ExecuteAsync>b__27_0() in CareerDetails.cshtml
+
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ScheduledTrackName", new { scheduledTrackId = "@Model.Class.ScheduledTrackId" })

[image: ScheduledClass from Object Explorer]

[image: Scheduled Track from Object Explorer]

There is a foreign key constraint on Classes (ScheduledClass) into ScheduledTrack.
There is no foreign key constraint on Tracks whatsoever.
There is also no foreign key constraint on ScheduledTracks whatsoever.

I have tried:

- Deleting the database completely (It is a remodel of an old database...So I just pull in the current production ....run the conversion script again and we can start fresh).
- Running dotnet ef tools scaffolding the entire database and putting the resulting Models and Fluent API code into a separate directory, then carefully comparing each table to how I have it vs how EF thinks it should be.  EF does not put TrackId in either of the classes (ScheduledTrack or ScheduledClass) and any differences were added and are shown.
- I have queries sysColumns and confirmed there are only two tables that have TrackId.  Tracks and TrackCourses. Like I said, there is no CODE relationship or SQL relationship between these two tables and either of the tables I'm talking about (ScheduledTrack or ScheduledClass)

Is there some place that EF puts some cached version of what it thinks the metedata looks like?  It seems to be stuck!

Somethings you might think...found after searching for my problem solution at length:

- There is no replication.
- There is no edmx (obviously).
- I am not using Migrations.
- I am just using pure code-first where the database already exists.
- The relationship from ScheduledClass, I thought, was well established into ScheduledTrack where it should not just be making up some shadow property called TrackId...and if it did, why would it call it TrackId?
- There is no other related entity in ScheduledClass that contains the property ScheduledTrackId

Comment: Just reverse enginer using a tool

Comment: As I mentioned I did use the EF Scaffolding tool and compared what my (old) code was compared to the generated code.  Neglible Maxlength markings and such was all I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It USED to link to Track, shown in case someone wants to cling to its importance

Actually for EF Core you are *still* linking them

```cs
public class Track : AuditableEntity
{
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<ScheduledTrack> ScheduledTracks { get; set; } // <--
}
```

EF Core documentation for relationships contains a section called [Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property) saying

> Including just one navigation property (no inverse navigation, and no foreign key property) is enough to have a relationship defined by convention.

and providing an example

> ```cs
> public class Blog
> {
>    public int BlogId { get; set; }
>    public string Url { get; set; }
>
>    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Post
> {
>    public int PostId { get; set; }
>    public string Title { get; set; }
>    public string Content { get; set; }
> }
> ```

As I understand, you used to have an explicit FK property and/or reference navigation property and/or fluent configuration in/for `Track` entity, which you have removed. But, the remained collection navigation property still defines a conventional relationship with `TrackId` shadow FK property in `ScheduledTrack`, and a column named "TrackId" in the associated table.

In other words, the entity model does not match the database. Reverse engineering does not help because you probably compare the primitive properties and do not pay attention to the generated navigation properties. And in such cases it is much more important to know what EF Core *thinks* database is, because all behaviors (queries, inserts, updates etc.) are based on that and not the real database structure. After all, they are ORM (Object Relational Mapping), and if your mapping is incorrect, you get unexpected behaviors/errors.

To recap, if you really want to remove a FK relationship, make sure to remove (additionally to the explicit FK property if any and the reference navigation property if any) all navigation properties targeting that entity (either as reference, or as collection element).

In this particular case, simply remove `Track.ScheduledTracks`.

Comment: I read your comment twice.  The first time, I refuted what you stated.  The second time, it jumped out at me like one of those videos where you watch something innocent like a car driving along the peaceful road and then a ghostly image pops up and fills your screen.  I guess that'll teach me to post something snarky (which you expertly quoted for effect).  I'll see if finishing the link on the ScheduledTrack side fixes this monstrously annoying issue.

Comment: Ivan ScheduledClasses contain the foreign key to the course it is an instance of....which TrackCourses used to have a foreign key constraint into.  I removed both that Foreign Key constraint AND the single navigation property.  There is now nothing I see in code, nor in the DB that could relate these two together, yet the error remains.  Feel like I'm being extra dense here.  Like maybe I can't see the forest for the trees!

Comment: Hmm, ScheduledClasses? TrackCourses? These are irrelevant. The problem as I see it was in (`Track`, `ScheduledTrack` ) relationship. The invalid assumed non existing FK column should have been `ScheduledTracks.TrackId`, and removing `ScheduledTracks` property from the `Track` class should have fixed it. Btw, you can turn on the EF Core SQL query logging and see the generated SQL and the invalid table column. Or just do `_DB.ScheduledTracks.ToQueryString()` in Debug/Watch and see the string (also eventually include it in the question so we can see it as well).

Comment: Yeah - I was always seeing the query.  That's how I deduced that it was trying to get that TrackId from ScheduledTracks.  Thanks for your help on this.  After a I cleaned the project and rebuilt - I got a different error (which I was expecting to have to deal with)